# How to correctly compile a C# package?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!

I have trouble building a C# package due to the error:

```
  /home/berln/projects/ros/roscsharp/hello_world/src/hello.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `RosCS' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
```

I created a simple C# package by

```
  berln@berln-Signor:~/projects/ros/roscsharp$ roscreate-pkg hello_world
```

Then I edited manifest.xml and added this line.

```
  <depend package="roscs"/>
```

And the last thing I changed is CMakeLists.txt, and I added these three lines:

```
  rosbuild_include(roscs cncs)
  CSHARP_ADD_TARGET_DEPENDENCY(hello Mono.C5) 
  CSHARP_ADD_EXE(hello src/hello.cs)
```

Here's the src/hello.cs:

```
  using System;
  using System.Threading;
  using RosCS;

  public class RosCsHello
  {
      Node node;
      public RosCsHello()
      {
          this.node = Node.MainNode;
      }
      public void Run() 
      {
          while(RosSharp.Ok()) 
          {
              Console.WriteLine("Hello");
          }
      }

      static public void Main ()
      {   
          RosSharp.Init("ROSCS_hello",args);
          RosCsHello hello = new RosCsHello();
          hello.Run();
      }   
  }
```

But when I compile, the compiler would complain that it cannot find RosCS, I don't know why this happens?

### EDIT:

I followed what Alireza suggested, I first modify my CMakeLists.txt, and then remove Makefile autogenerated by roscreate-pkg.After that, I cmake CMakeLists.txt, then make.

But I got this error message:

```
[ 14%] Creating Csharp Wrapper Code
Querying Ros for messages...
Message: Name: Logger NameSpace: roscpp/
Start generating...
Path for generating files : /home/rosfuerte/project/ros/my_package/roscs_try/msg_cs_gen!
Total msges: 1
Cleaning before...
Template: /home/rosfuerte/project/ros/important_packages/cn-roscs-ros-pkg/roscs/templates/messages/Message.cs
Template: /home/rosfuerte/project/ros/important_packages/cn-roscs-ros-pkg/roscs/templates/messages/Node.cs
Template: /home/rosfuerte/project/ros/important_packages/cn-roscs-ros-pkg/roscs/templates/messages/Publisher.cs
Template: /home/rosfuerte/project/ros/important_packages/cn-roscs-ros-pkg/roscs/templates/messages/RosSharp.cs
Template: /home/rosfuerte/project/ros/important_packages/cn-roscs-ros-pkg/roscs/templates/messages/Timer.cs
Template: /home/rosfuerte/project/ros/important_packages/cn-roscs-ros-pkg/roscs/templates/messages/roscs.cpp
Template: /home/rosfuerte/project/ros/important_packages/cn-roscs-ros-pkg/roscs/templates/messages/Subscriber.cs.pm
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `lib/std_msgs.Messages.dll', needed by `lib/roscs_try.Communication.dll'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/CSharp_myExe_exe.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

rosbuild_init()
rosbuild_include(roscs cncs) 
rosbuild_gen_cs_msg()

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

CSHARP_ADD_TARGET_DEPENDENCY(myExe Mono.C5)
CSHARP_ADD_EXE(myExe src/tmp.cs)
```

Does anyone have ideas about how this problem can be solved? Any thought or advice would be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35018/how-to-correctly-compile-a-c#-package?/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2012-05-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Just edit your CMakeList.txt to something like this:

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6)
include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)

rosbuild_init()
rosbuild_include(roscs cncs)

rosbuild_gen_cs_msg()


set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)

CSHARP_ADD_TARGET_DEPENDENCY(test_cs Mono.C5 )

CSHARP_ADD_EXE(test_cs src/test_cs.cs)
```

---

Originally posted by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) with karma: 717 on 2012-11-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-09**:
Thanks! By following you CMakelists.txt, I can now successfully rosmake. But the binary appeared in /bin is test_cs.exe.mdb(I assumed it should be an executable test_cs.exe). Do you have this situation?

**Comment by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) on 2012-11-09**:
no, i have both of them! just try to remove every auto generated files in the package directory and use cmake CMakeList.txt and then "make" command in order to compile the package.

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-11-09**:
Weird...I removed Makefile generated automatically and cmake CMakeLists.txt, but my make fails.Thanks a lot, I'll update my question. I'll try tomorrow, it's late here.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I had the same problem and adding `rosbuild_gen_cs_msg()` to CMakeList.txt just below `rosbuild_include(roscs cncs)` solved it.

Hope it helps.

---

Originally posted by [Olivier R.](https://answers.ros.org/users/2659/olivier-r./) with karma: 11 on 2012-06-24

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on 2012-06-30**:
I tried that solution before but it didn't work.
Can you share your succeeded package to me?
I want to compare mine and yours to find the difference. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed the problem!!

Surprising nobody has gotten around to compiling a C# package in almost a year. The answer is this:

Add

To your manifest.xml. Those messages will magically get compiled and put into your lib directory.

---

Originally posted by [mklingen](https://answers.ros.org/users/7191/mklingen/) with karma: 38 on 2013-09-27

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1